# App Quits when button is pressed

Tags: ios, xcode

i am making a soundboard app and when i run it in Xcode, after i click one of the buttons to play the sound i get an error. This is the Log of the crash

> 2012-07-14 20:24:34.395 SoundBoard[15374:c07] Could not load the
>   "BG.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier
>   "Apple.SoundBoard" 2012-07-14 20:24:41.645 SoundBoard[15374:c07]
>   -[ViewController playSound1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x93a99b0 2012-07-14 20:24:41.648 SoundBoard[15374:c07] (null)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception (lldb)

Any help? i can't figure it out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the `-playSound1` method on your `ViewController` class.

Comment: I have defined it as an "- (IBAction)playsound1;"

Comment: There is no denying it.  You didn't implement that method in the class ViewController.  Maybe you defined it but didn't implement it?  Or you defined it in a different class?

Comment: Maybe, now that i look back over my code, i see an "incomplete implementation" error in the "ViewController.m" file. Could this be it? How would i fix it?

Comment: `- (IBAction)playSound1 {}` in your `@implementation`.

Comment: @JonMihail Is capitalization a problem? In your comment above you said (possibly copied in) "- (IBAction)playsound1;" (lowercase S) but in your error output above it says "playSound1" (with capital S).

Comment: YES!!!!! Thanks for everyones help but Jeff hit it on the head! just a stupid Capitol error by me

Answer (score 0):

You have no implementation of -playsound1 on your view controller.
It's defined in the header, but not implemented, hence the warning.

Just implement the method (making it play a sound) and it'll work.